AWS S3 Bucket Policy and CORS Configured, Yet Getting Access Denied on URL
I am trying to make objects in my S3 bucket accessible via URL, but when I hit the object URL in the browser, I receive the following error:
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0491CC51TEK93R1P</RequestId>
<HostId>aQ9zYuEQ/a5DkwjgbPSkKzfalVuxyYcne8DDIwzSWKo6zhqAovy5U8+PAon5A7OdKfh0KVB/04g=</HostId>
</Error>

Here are my current configurations:
Bucket Policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*****:role/xyz"
            },
            "Action": "S3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
        }
    ]
}

CORS Configuration:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]

I have turned off the Block all public access settings in my bucket.
What could be the reason behind this AccessDenied error when hitting the object URL directly in the browser? Is there something wrong with my bucket policy, CORS configuration, or the settings?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Nothing at all to do with CORS

Either you should create a pre-signed URL or make the objects public to make them accessible via URL to anyone if I got you. If you want it for specific roles then the same policy should work for xyz role after signing in to AWS account. No need for cros in this case

Yes, obviously, but I made sure to include all the relevant information here. I will upload the images soon, and they will be used.

@AsfarIrshad I uploaded the image using a PreSigned URL, and it was successfully uploaded. However, when I tried to access it through the URL, it showed an 'access denied' error. I also attempted to upload the image using the upload option provided by AWS S3, but encountered the same issue.

You need another predigend url to view / get the object or change the policy to actually allow public access.

@luk2302 Can you please let me know from where I can allow public access?

Pre-Signed URL for upload and download/view are different, you can't use the same one. Need to generate a new one. If you are unable to upload using console and this policy is a match with your role, it means there is some other policy or SCP which is denying your access

@AsfarIrshad I am able to upload the image using the console, but when I copy the URI and paste it in the browser, it shows the same 'access denied' error.
Each time I need to access the image, do I have to generate a PreSigned URL, or is it only necessary to generate it once?

It depends on the expiry, you can specify how long you want it to be valid during generation, and can be used unlimited times during that time period

You generally need a new one every time since it is blind to the expiry of the credentials creating the url which generally have a max expiration of 12 hours. Alternative: put a CloudFront in front of the bucket.

So, based on my requirement, I don't want to generate a presigned URL every time and I need to access the image through a direct URL, as I need to display it in the React frontend. Is there any other conventional method you can suggest other than using a presigned URL?
Thanks for sharing the information.

make the bucket public or (much better) put a CloudFront in front it. There are a million tutorials and explanations on that out there.

The issue is that the browser has no AWS IAM credentials, this issue does not have anything to do with CORS, you would receive an error from the browser, not from s3. If you want to make requests from the browser you will either have to create an s3 presigned url as Asfar Irshad and Luk2302 suggested:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html
Or you will have to add the authentication signature to the request headers yourself:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html
You can also make the objects publicly accessible or go through a cloudfront distribution. In general it's not great to always go through s3, with cloudfront you get caching at the edge and it is cheaper than going through s3 every time.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/
